# cuda; using device memory shared

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

Each thread in a block can have different set (and size) of results. At the moment i am allocating fixed size of device memory; think per-thread.

Meaning, for XX threads i Have to allocate XX * max_result_count * data_structure * sizeof(int), my data contains integers. Each thread access its memory block (offset) by calculating int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; and multiplying it with max_result_count*data_structure, for integer array;

In the real world this means huge waste of device memory, because some sets are close to 0, some are not. For example, i Have to allocate under 2GB of device memory to be able to store an equivalent of 300MB of results.

Any ideas on how to rework this ?

For example, each thread locks mutex, increments actual res_count, writes data into shared memory block, unlocks mutex.

[Problem solved, thanks, guys !]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already hinted in your question at one possible approach:

```
#define DSIZE (100*1048576)

__device__ unsigned int buffer_index = 0;
__device__ int *buffer_data;
```

In your host code:

```
int *buffer_data_temp;
cudaMalloc(&buffer_data_temp, sizeof(int)*DSIZE); 
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(buffer_data, &buffer_data_temp, sizeof(int *));
```

In your thread code:

```
unsigned int my_buffer_offset = atomicAdd(&buffer_index, size_of_my_thread_data);
assert((my_buffer_offset+size_of_my_thread_data) < DSIZE);
memcpy(buffer_data+my_buffer_offset, my_thread_data, size_of_my_thread_data*sizeof(int));
```

(disclaimer: coded in browser, not tested)

It's not necessary to use a mutex, for example around the `memcpy` operation.  Once we have reserved the starting and ending points of our allocation with the `atomicAdd`, the threads will not step on each other, even if all are writing data, because they are writing to separate regions within `buffer_data`.

EDIT: 
Here's a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define DSIZE (100*1048576)
#define nTPB 32
#define BLKS 2

__device__ unsigned int buffer_index = 0;

__global__ void update_buffer(int *buffer_data){
  const unsigned int size_of_my_thread_data = 1;
  unsigned int my_buffer_offset = atomicAdd(&buffer_index, size_of_my_thread_data);
  assert((my_buffer_offset+size_of_my_thread_data) < DSIZE);
  int my_thread_data[size_of_my_thread_data];
  my_thread_data[0] = (blockIdx.x*10000) + threadIdx.x;
  memcpy(buffer_data+my_buffer_offset, my_thread_data, size_of_my_thread_data*sizeof(int));
}

int main(){

  int *h_buffer_data, *d_buffer_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_buffer_data, sizeof(int)*DSIZE);
  update_buffer<<<BLKS, nTPB>>>(d_buffer_data);
  unsigned int result_size;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&result_size, buffer_index, sizeof(unsigned int));
  h_buffer_data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*result_size);
  cudaMemcpy(h_buffer_data, d_buffer_data, result_size*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < result_size; i++)
    printf("%d\n", h_buffer_data[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: funny, im having trouble using cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(). will cry here, if im not able to get it work.

Comment: You don't have to use a device symbol based pointer to the buffer data.  You can use an ordinary `cudaMalloc` created `buffer_data` region, and pass the start of that region as a parameter to the kernel.

Comment: im trying to get working your code. cannot use assert, compiler says, you cannot use host functions in device/global functions. could you possibly add code that increments `positive` local result counter ? because in my code, sum of locally incremented positives differ from (buffer_index/size_of_my_thread_data). hopefully you get what i mean.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean.  The assert is not essential, it's just a safety check.  You're getting the assert error because it's only supported in devices of cc2.0 and greater.

Comment: put simply, `buffer_index/size_of_my_thread_data` differs from accumulated, locally, in threads incremented variables - i have a loop in `update_buffer` and i increment local integer in case of success (case when i have to memcopy data structure) and after main loop i copy array of these variables (one for each thread) to host memory and in host code, add them to see `total number` of successful iterations. `total number` differs from `buffer_index/size_of_my_thread_data`.

Comment: I would say there's probably a bug in the code you're describing, which you haven't shown at all.  If you think there's a bug in the code I've provided in its entirety with a sample test case, please point it out.

Comment: yes, it was a bug in my code. this code works perfectly fine, thank you. my problem solved !

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the kernel and calling function to calculate a part of the required points (obviously, you'll have to change the number of blocks per launch, etc.).

```
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numKernelLaunches; i++) {
    yourKernel<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(offset, /* your other parameters */);
    offset += numBlocks*threadsPerBlock;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

and in `yourKernel` you keep `int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;` as the index for the global memory access and `i + offset` for the id of your data position.